# SQL, finding other entries based on them having one attribute in common the same

Tags: sql, oracle

Please pardon my bad English. I have a table which looks like the below:

> Book(BookID, Title)
>
> Author(BookID, AuthID)

And there's a certain book, say it's ID 52. I need to find the other books by the authors who wrote the book with the ID of 52, but not include ID 52 in the list of IDs that I output.

So I assume that I can `JOIN` the two tables, but the problem is that I can't use a sub-query, so I'm stuck here. I have a feeling that I'm supposed to be using `WHERE`, but I'm not sure how to do it as thus far all I can figure out how to get is a list of the authors who are assigned to the book with `WHERE Author.BookID = 52`.

```
select Book.BookID
from Book
join Author
on Book.BookID=Author.BookID
```

Is there a way to get the AuthID of those who are assigned to the book with ID 52 and then output the other books they are assigned to? And then `MINUS` the ID 52 book away? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Again, any help or point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't your `book` table have and `authid` foreign key into the `author` table, rather than having a `bookid` in `author`?

Comment: @AlexPoole That would make more sense, but unfortunately, I'm working with something pre-built and since I'm new, I'm not trusted with changing things yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to find all other books of the same author as the author of a given BookId, right?

```
SELECT b.BookId 
FROM   Author a 
       INNER JOIN Author b ON a.AuthID = b.AuthID AND a.BookId <> b.BookId
WHERE  a.BookId = 52;
```

Comment: Thank you. It appears as though that works! :) So you're giving each instance of the table an alias so you can run it against itself and then ensuring that when it searches through it matches the `AuthID` but not the `BookID` on the ones it finds, is that it?

Comment: Your´re right. One table alias is required to determine the AuthId of the given book, the other for selecting all other books of that author.